d3js dimension of div inside node when toggle display
In the following code snippet the display attribute of <div class="details" style="display: none;"> is toggled on click. The text within details-container is cut off by the width of the node, when display attribute is set to "none" by default.
If the display attribute is set to "block" by default, the text is not cut off. However, the dimensions of the details container remain the same in both cases.


const data = [
    { customId: 1, customParentId: null, customName: 'node1' },
    { customId: 2, customParentId: 1, customName: 'node2' },
    { customId: 3, customParentId: 1, customName: 'node3' },
  ];

    chart = new d3.OrgChart()
      .nodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customId)
      .parentNodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customParentId)
      .nodeWidth((node) => 100)
      .nodeHeight((node) => 100)
      .nodeUpdate(myNodeUpdate)
      .nodeContent((node) => {
        return `<div customId="${node.data.customId}" 
            style="background-color:aqua;width:${node.width}px;height:${node.height}px"> 
            <div class="click">click</div>
            <div class="details" style="display: none;">
              Random Text Random Text Random Text Random Text
            </div>
               
           </div>`;
      })
      .container('.chart-container')
      .data(data).render();
     
function myNodeUpdate(d, i, arr) {
  const button = d3.select(this).select(".click");
  var details = d3.select(this).select(".details");
  button.on("click", function(){
      toggleContainer(details);
    });
}
 function toggleContainer(div){
    if (div.style("display") === 'none' || div.style("display") === '') {
      div.style("display", 'block');
    } else {
      div.style("display", 'none');
    }
  }
    
.details {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 0.3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-org-chart@3.0.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-flextree@2.1.2/build/d3-flextree.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container"></div>



